# call a method with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this code to try and call a method from my controller in codeigniter,

```
$("#Blog").click(function () {
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax ({
            url: "index.php/home/category",
            type: "POST",
            success : function (html) {
                $("#right-content").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

The ajax does not seem to be getting fired, is there something that I am missing, the #Blog represents the ID of a link in my navigation menu, all that happens is the link works as normal.

Someone please help :-(

Comment: It is worth noting that the method called gets the URI of the URL to construct a database query, so I am unsure as to whether POST is right parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the normal link behavior from taking place.

```
$("#Blog").click(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    // Block the normal click action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create post
    $.post (
        "index.php/home/category", // <- request URI
        {url: url},                // <- any data goes here
        function (html) {          // <- callback
            $("#right-content").append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you might want to check out the documentation for [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post).

Answer (score 1):

If you are overridding clicking on anchors, remember to block the default behavior of the link (i.e. jumping to the linked page).

So you might start with a change:

```
$("#Blog").click(function (ev) {
           ev.preventDefault();
           var url = // ... the rest as before.
```